# How can I simulate a double-tap event on a Scene View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

Background: I have an app presenting a 3D model with SceneKit. By default SceneKit has a function that once the user makes a double-tap, the 3D model returns into its original position. I want to use this feature programmatically. When the user hits a certain button, the 3D model shall return to its original position. Therefore, I would like to fire a double-tap event if possible and hope that the 3D model will react accordingly.
How can this be done?

This question relates to another case [How to retrieve information about the camera position in a sceneKit project when the 3D model is zoomed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815745/how-to-retrieve-information-about-the-camera-position-in-a-scenekit-project-when) in which I try to resolve this task by setting the cameranode positions to their original value. But obviously this is not possible. The fake of the double-click would be a kind of work around in order to achieve the requirement for my application.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24768474/2997825 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/70779030/2997825 SceneKit will create a new node and set it as the point of view when an interaction starts.

To revert to the original camera, you can simply set the `pointOfView` property back to the original, untouched, camera node.

Comment: I have tried to realize a solution with the pointOfView parameters. However these tests confirmed that the postion.z is not changed by a zoom and does also not react to changes. This is different from position.x and position.y. I am currently working on an old Xcode 10 environment due to hardware restrictions. I have ordered a new iMac and will soon be able to use Xcode 14. Then I will make this test again and make a further comment here.